# Asp.net Data list paging without page refresh

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I want to apply paging using datalist with out page refresh in asp.net

My Code Structure is below.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgress" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div id="something">
            <img alt="progress" src="loader.gif" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
         Paging Items 
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dlPagingg" EventName="ItemCommand" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:DataList ID="DataListProducts" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="DataListProducts_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemStyle CssClass="listing-pro-img-main" VerticalAlign="Top" />
    <ItemTemplate>
         Product List Here
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

**Issue:** When user click on page number in paging list, paging change with appropriate page number , but products in datalist product not refresh.

i have also debug that all code file getting product and assign to datasource property of DataListProducts like,

```
 DataListProducts.DataSource = {New Product List}
 DataListProducts.DataBind();
```

Can you please advise me where issue is?

Comment: post server side code .cs

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery DataTable
To wrap your table on the client side and then get the option to page, sort and filter you columns.
No refresh, no postback and no url changes.